# SXA Search functionality works only with the whole search query

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, I implemented search functionality using Search box and Search results OOB SXA components, When I search with a sentence, it only returns the exact match for the whole sentence, If I have search results that contains part of the sentence not the whole, they aren't returned. 
For example, if I search with "Dragon cars", the returned results must contains the whole query, the results that contains "Dragon" or "cars" are not returned.

Comment: Do you search in a RTE field? or Single Line? Is it Title or Display Name field?

Comment: I'm searching at only single or multi line fields like Title or Description.

Comment: Does partial search work in multiline Description field?

Comment: Yes it works well

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SXA search renderings, then you are not exactly searching by Title or Description fields. The SXA search is using AggregatedContent computed field (`sxacontent` in the index) and is using `Contains` method on it like this:

```
predicate = predicate.And(i => i.AggregatedContent.Contains(t));
```

where `t` is the text phrase, you are looking for.

The AggregatedContent will contain the text from Title and Description field so the `Contains` should give you the results and I'm pretty sure it is working fine. But once again you are searching in the AggregatedContent filed, not Title or Description itself.

Take a look at the item fields and how it looks like in the index:

[image]